# Reverse Lookup in django joined tables does not work

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django, orm

I just created a model as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    
    class Meta:
         db_table = "ax"


class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
 
    class Meta:
         db_table = "bx"


class Z(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    class Meta:
         db_table = "zx"
```

I want to get list of `A.name`s when `B.slug == input_str`.
What I've tried in view.py so far:

```
def myView(request, input_str):
    context = {
        'inputs_list': A.objects.filter(bx__slug__startswith=input_str).select_related('ax').select_related('bx').values('name')
        }
    return render(request, 'app/my_template.html', context)
```

This returns an error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'bx' into field. Choices are:zx, id, name,
> slug...

---

**My Question:**

What is the correct lookup for returning `A.name` if `B.slug= input_str`. Or better say, how filter A based on a column in B?

```
A.objects.filter(bx__slug__startswith=input_str).select_related('ax').select_related('bx').values('name')
```

---

Comment: Did you walk through the Django tutorial?

Comment: Yes, but couldn't find anything helpful!